# distcp not working between hadoop version 2.0.0 and 0.20

Tags: hadoop

During distcp between two version of hadoop i am getting below error:

**Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 3**

I am using below command:
   hadoop distcp

Solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

distcp does not work between version from hdfs:// to hdfs://

You must run the distcp on the destination cluster and use the hftp:// protocol (a read-only protocol) on the source cluster.

Note: the default ports are different for different protocols, so the command ends up looking like:

```
hadoop distcp hftp://<source>:50070/<src path> hdfs://<dest>:8020/<dest path>
```

or, if you prefer fake values

```
hadoop distcp hftp://foo.company.com:50070/data/baz hdfs://bar.compnay.com:8020/data/
```